# How to shuffle products on category page when you refresh the page in magento2?

Tags: list, reference, magento2, product, categories

How to shuffle products on category page when you refresh the page in magento2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Mahendra try this solution!!

First Override your list.phtml file in your custom theme.
Add this code in your list.phtml file.

**$productArray = iterator_to_array($_productCollection);
shuffle($productArray);**

and add this $productArray in foreach loop.

cacheable="false" in your catalog_category_view.xml file.

<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml" **cacheable="false"**>